# Convergence of angle between vectors?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

This problem comes is from Hoffman's *Analysis in Euclidean Space*.

---

**True or False**. Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^m$. If $\{X_{n}\}$ converges to a (nonzero) vector $X$, does the angle between the vectors $X_n$ and $X$ converge to $0$?

I am assuming it is true. Here is my attempt at a proof.

---

**Proof.** Assume that $\{X_{n}\}$ converges to the vector $X$. We know that 
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\langle X,X_n\rangle}{|X||X_n|}$$
for some positive integer $n$. 
Since 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\langle X,X_n\rangle}{|X||X_n|} =\frac{|X|^2}{|X|^2}=1$$
then $$\theta=\cos^{-1}(1)=0$$

---

I can't see a reason why the converse statement wouldn't be necessarily true. In other words, if the angle between ${X_{n}}$ and some vector $X$ approaches zero, wouldn't the sequence $\{X_n\}$ converge to $X$?

---

**EDIT:** Another thing that popped into my mind. Do these results hold in general for all vector spaces?

Comment: For your converse claim, what if the sequence converges to a scalar multiple of $X$?

Comment: Are you assuming $X \neq 0$?

Comment: So the converse claim does not hold. Got it.

Comment: @JairTaylor yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

The converse is not true because the angles do not speak to the norms. The angles may converge to a limit but the vectors do not have to converge due an oscillation in norms.

Comment: Thank you for checking. Could you say anything about my question in the edit?

Comment: If the vector space is an inner product space, where you can define norms then your result is valid.